# Any way to "reboot" a USB port on a Mac Mini?

Tags: mac, usb

I have an [IR Toy](http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/USB_Infrared_Toy) attached to my Mac Mini and it works but if I do not interact with it for awhile, it will not be reachable. I use the Mac Mini as a server and have turned off sleeping in Energy Saver settings. If I unplug and plug in the IR Toy, it works again.

Is there any way I can emulate this on the Mac? Preferably something I can automate with cron?

Comment: I believe it has to do with the kernel module that's responsible for the device, I have the same problem with an SD card reader on an Acer notebook, except that I can't use it after a suspension, and it only works again after a full power-off/turn on. Still, I haven't been able to find a solution.

Comment: Though apparently unplugging it helps for you: I wonder about the same thing when the USB controller has somehow shut down probably due to requesting too much power (though not actually *using* it). I had to reboot my MacBook to bring the USB ports back to life after I connected a non-powered hub for two USB relays...

Comment: If it was a storage device I would say `sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions/IOUSBMassStorageClass.kext` will likely work. I don't know which kext your IR Toy is using, but finding out which one and unloading it should work.